# Google webmaster ignores certain keywords?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I'm trying to improve our search ranking for 'mock web services' or 'web service mocks' however I've hit a problem - Google webmaster doesnt list 'web services' / 'webservices' / 'web-services' as a Content Keyword even though all variants are on our site.

Does Google and / or webmaster ignore certain words like 'web' because they are too common?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm sure you dont need to include all variants of a word to be relevant for that term, not only is google cleverer than that but it might not look consistent to your users.)

Yes, Google can ignore certain words or phrases, though the keyword content is just a frequency count. It doesnt mean you will or wont rank for terms listed. :

> Q: Why do my Webmaster Tools stats show common phrases such as "buy
>   now" that are not directly related to my site? A: **While some common
>   words and phrases are filtered by Webmaster Tools,** there may be some
>   that you use which are not. Having these words or phrases listed in
>   your Webmaster Tools account does not mean that our algorithms will
>   view your site as being only relevant for those keywords. While
>   Webmaster Tools mostly counts the occurences of words on your site,
>   our web-search algorithms use well over 200 other factors for
>   crawling, indexing and ranking. In other words: don't worry if you see
>   keywords like this listed in your Webmaster Tools account.
>
> https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq--webmaster-tools#strange-words2

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind is that this list is based on what was crawled - it doesn't mean that these words are seen as the most relevant when it comes to ranking.